# How can I upload and read a file on a raspberry pi running Windows 10 IoT

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I have built a app that read a config file and load a dictionary based on the xml. 
What I want is to not need to add that file to the program. Instead I want to be able to upload to the pi3 and then tell the program to refresh and read the file I uploaded.  It loads the file included with the code to an obscure folder.
How can I upload and specify the path in my code to a folder that is easier to get to.

Thanks in advance

Comment: we have a dedicated stack exchange for Raspberry Pi - try posting your question there https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can check [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) and [read a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files#reading-from-a-file) in UWP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Windows.Storage** namespace and following the below code for creating,accessing and other operations like these in Folder and Files on UWP.

```
            //Get Installation Folder for current application
            StorageFolder rootFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

            //Create a folder in the root folder of app if not exist and open if exist.
            StorageFolder Folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync(yourFolderName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            //Craete a file in your folder if not exist and replace it with new file if exist
            StorageFile sampleFile = await Folder.CreateFileAsync("samplefile.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            //Create your text and write it on your configuaration file
            string yourText = "Your Sample Text or Configuration";
            await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, yourText);
```

After that you can get access the file again read your configuration value from that form ReadTextAsync method.

```
            //Read data from file
            await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
```